# Right align and rotate text to the right edge

Tags: html, css

Good day, I am trying to make sure I show a rounded rectangle to the right of my screen with some text. For the most part, it works well, but when I switch language to Russian, the alignment goes awry. English and other international languages (including Arabic!) work fine - the text is always aligned to the right. The text in question is the yellow box to the right. I'm pretty sure its my hard coded right - but how do I make sure it sticks to the right? float:right, text-align:right don't work

thanks
(please click on the image to see animation between english and russian)

[image]

The alignment code:

CSS:

```
.bwmode {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: -28px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bwmode" ng-if="$root.runMode=='lowbw'">
            <span translate="kLowBWDisplay"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way to do it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbvp6gu/1/)

```
  p{
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translateY(-50%:);
       right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: genius! what the heck is writing-mode!!!! but works well on desktop - I'll try on a mobile tomorrow and if it works, I'll accept it.

Comment: this unfortunately does not work on mobiles (writing-mode: vertical-lr) - just tried in iOS 10. Any other ideas? Also tried -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr

Comment: oops sorry - it works after adding `-webkit-writing-mode`!